# How to view browsing history in brave?

Tags: browser, history, brave

I've tried all the short-cuts and UI options I use in other browsers and can't find anything about this online. Just keep getting stuff about the browser in general.
[69 shortcuts](https://shortcutworld.com/Brave-Browser/win/Brave-Browser_Shortcuts) don't include history...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can view the browsing history by putting `about:history` into the address bar.

You can also shortcut to it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> (used to be <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd>).

Comment: No idea why they didn't just use `Ctrl+H` like **every other browser** already uses...

Comment: Ctrl+H works now.

Answer (score 1):

this shortcut (Ctrl + Y) does nothing in Brave.
About:history does the same thing as the 3 bar menu upper right does. It brings you to the history page, but only allows you to clear history, unless you click on the left side of the url history when the hand with the finger pointer comes on. It didn't used to be like this, it used to only be a list of urls that you just click on.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).